# PHP version in webserver is different to PHP version in terminal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I'm using valet and have just created a fresh Laravel 10 project. One of my other projects requires PHP 7.3, so I switch between this and other versions using `valet use php@X.X`. For my new project, I switched to php 8.2 (verified this using `php -v`) but when I try to access the site in my browser, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0". You are running 7.3.33. in **/Users/user/projects/my-project/vendor/composer/platform_check.php** on line **24***

I'm not sure where it's getting that I'm running 7.3 from. `composer -vvv` gives 'Running 2.3.1 (2022-03-30 15:41:28) with PHP 8.2.12 on Darwin / 19.6.0' and `php -v` also gives 8.2?

I've tried:

```bash
rm ~/.config/valet/valet.sock
valet restart
```

but this didn't fix the error I'm getting in my browser

Comment: Try `valet use php@8.2 --force`. If that doesn't help, `which php`; maybe the system version is being used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check Valet Configuration:
Verify that Valet is correctly configured to use PHP 8.2. You can check this by running `valet use php@8.2` in the terminal. If it's already set to PHP 8.2, try switching to a different version and then back to PHP 8.2.